# Can div element fixed position when the size change?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm trying to resize a ruler.

When is in **horizontal** mode, it extends and shrinks when you resize it. 
But in the **vertical** mode, the ruler moves to left the more your shrink it, and moves to right when you extend it.

You can resize the ruler dragging the little red line.

---

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bst6G/).

And here is part of the source:

```
ruler.css({
    width: e.pageY -ruler.offset().top
});
```

Full source is here:

```
$.event.add( document, "mousemove", function(e){
e.stopPropagation(e);
if(ruler_resize_active) {
    console.log(".ruler-resize:mousemove");
    console.log(ruler.offset().left);
    console.log(ruler.offset().top);
    if(options.orientation == "vertical") {
            ruler.css({
             width: e.pageY - ruler.offset().top
        });
            }
     }
});
```

Comment: Your question is lacking in details. What are you trying to do? What does "it works fine" mean?

Comment: im sorry, im not good in english.. T_T it works fine means > when I make ruler style  horizontal. And then try to resize div it works fine. but when I made vertical style ruler, and then while resize div, it position is changing while resize...

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do. Some screenshots of the result you are expecting will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks all comments.. I just want only change the size(vertically), please visit >> http://jsfiddle.net/Bst6G/ << and then drag red point area..

Comment: @ChoHongRae - Ya, you should add that "red point" bit to the question body.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen im sorry, i can't understand you said TT

Comment: Hey everyone! Cho Hong Rae tries to resize a ruler. It extends and shrinks when you resize it without moving in the horizontal mode. But if you try to resize the ruler in the vertical mode the ruler moves to left the more your shrink it, and moves to right when you extend it. I think the problem relies on `ruler_wrapper.append('<div class="ruler-label" style="left: '+i+'px">'+i+'</div>');` You may add a correction coefficent as addition to i value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know jQuery, so I can’t tell you the most optimal way to add the fix, but if I understand your issue, you just need to set a transform-origin. The default is center center, so the center point moves when you resize. If you set it to something like top left, it will work as expected.

As an example, I added it for webKit (using its prefix) in the CSS you add to ruler:

```
var ruler = $(this)
    .addClass('ruler')
    .css({
        minWidth: options.minWidth,
        maxWidth: options.maxWidth,
        width: options.width,
        webkitTransformOrigin: "top left"
    });
```

You should instead set it in the correct place you'd usually set it in jQuery, with whatever method jQuery uses to set the transform-origin (likely right before you apply the rotate, or some added parameter). You should also add the various other prefixes, and the prefixless version. For the unprefixed version it should be `transformOrigin` (lowercase t).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bst6G/3/

Comment: You need to add the unprefixed version, such as transformOrigin: "top left". For Opera it is OTransformOrigin: "top left", and for Firefox: MozTransformOrigin: "top left"